# How to define TypeScript types for a state machine with actions and handle type inference for action arguments?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a problem with the state argument. I want it to infer the return type of the state function but I can't make it work.

```
function createMachine<
  T extends {
    state: () => Record<string, any>
    actions: {
      [state: string]: {
        [action: string]: (state: ReturnType<T['state']>) => any
      }
    }
  }
>(_: T) {
  /* ... */
}

createMachine({
  state: () => ({ username: 'hello' }),
  actions: {
    IDLE: {
      login(state) {
        console.log(state.username) // The argument type is now Record<string, any>
      }
    }
  }
})
```

I already tried to create K Generic and then pass it to the return type of the `state: () => K`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generic you declare doesn't affect the return of the `state` function. Instead of using `T` on the whole object just use it on the state itself:

```
function createMachine<T>(_: {
  state: () => T;
  actions: {
    [state: string]: {
      [action: string]: (state: T) => any;
    };
  };
}) {
  /* ... */
}

createMachine({
  state: () => ({ username: 'hello' }),
  actions: {
    IDLE: {
      login(state) {
        console.log(state.username); // {username: string}
      },
    },
  },
});
```

[playground](https://tsplay.dev/w6prym)